# Finding flaw in proof

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

This is one of the problem I have been working on Velleman's `How to prove` book:

> **Incorrect Theorem.** Suppose $\mathcal F$ and $\mathcal G$ are families of sets. If $\bigcup\mathcal F$ and $\bigcup\mathcal G$
> are disjoint, then so are $\mathcal F$ and $\mathcal G$. $(a)$ What’s wrong with the following
> proof of the theorem?

> **Proof.** Suppose $\bigcup\mathcal F$ and $\bigcup\mathcal G$ are disjoint. Suppose $\mathcal F$ and $\mathcal G$ are not
> disjoint. Then we can choose some set $A$ such that $A \in\mathcal F$ and $A \in\mathcal G$.
> Since $A \in\mathcal F$, by exercise $8$, $A\subseteq\bigcup\mathcal F$, so every element of $A$ is in $\bigcup\mathcal F$.
> Similarly, since $A \in\mathcal G$, every element of $A$ is in $\bigcup\mathcal G$. But then every
> element of $A$ is in both $\bigcup\mathcal F$ and $\bigcup\mathcal G$, and this is impossible since $\bigcup\mathcal F$ and
> $\bigcup\mathcal G$ are disjoint. Thus, we have reached a contradiction, so $\mathcal F$ and $\mathcal G$
> must be disjoint.

Even though, I have found an counterexample for the proof ($\mathcal F =
\{\{1\},\emptyset\}$ and $\mathcal G=\{\{2\}, \emptyset\}$), I'm not able to find any
flaw with this proof (it seems so convincing). Can anybody point me to what I'm missing?

Comment: Your counterexample shows the way. If $A=\emptyset$, then the fact that it is contained in both UF and UG doesn't tell you they overlap.

Comment: "Every element of $A$ is in both $\bigcup F$ and $\bigcup G$. Your example shows why this isn't a problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A good strategy is to  to run through the proof with your counter-example. The issue is that while it is also true for $A = \emptyset$ that every element of $A$ is in both $\cup F$ and $\cup G$ this does not contradict the assertion that the sets are disjoint. Only if there is an element in $A$, there is a contradiction.

Note that this also shows the the only set that can be common to both $F$ and $G$ is the empty set.

Comment: Thanks, I agree with that. But without thinking about $A = \{ \emptyset \}$, is it possible for me to find out the discrepancy in the proof ?

Comment: You are welcome. First a detail: be careful  $A = \{ \emptyset \}$ is not the same  as $A= \emptyset = \{ \}$. The former is not empty, but has the empty set as a unique element. (Analogy:a bag containing an empty bag is not an empty bag.)  I think yes it is also possible, one just has to be quite attentive. For each assertion one should think through if it is really true or just sounds true. But the pattern illustrated in this proof is quite a common one for pseudo-proofs. The thing to retain is: "for every" element something impossible happening is only a contradition if there is an element.

Comment: Thanks again. And yeah,  that should have been $A = \emptyset$ in my previous comment, typed it wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Your counterexample reveals a flawed implicit assumption in the proof. The contradiction the proof uses is based the fact that $A\subseteq\cup F$ and $A\subseteq\cup G$. It claims, based on this, that $\cup F$ and $\cup G$ are not disjoint. However, if $A=\emptyset$, then $A\subseteq S$ for *any* set $S$.