# Rectifying Proof

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

At the moment I read "How to Prove It" by Velleman.

I reached & solved the same exercise as in this question: [Finding flaw in proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1063507/finding-flaw-in-proof).

The exercise was formulated like this and the other asker had problems with finding the flaw (A could be empty).

> **Incorrect Theorem.** Suppose F and G are families of sets. If ∪F and ∪G
>   are disjoint, then so are F and G.
>
> (a) What’s wrong with the following
>   proof of the theorem?
>
> **Proof.** Suppose ∪F and ∪G are disjoint. Suppose F and G are not
>   disjoint. Then we can choose some set A such that A ∈ F and A ∈ G.
>   Since A ∈ F, by exercise 8, A ⊆ ∪F, so every element of A is in ∪F.
>   Similarly, since A ∈ G, every element of A is in ∪G. But then every
>   element of A is in both ∪F and ∪G, and this is impossible since ∪F and
>   ∪G are disjoint. Thus, we have reached a contradiction, so F and G
>       must be disjoint.

Then I asked myself: Would the theorem hold if you added the premise that $\forall x( (x \in F \wedge x \in G) \implies (x \neq \emptyset)) $? I think yes, but I'm not sure yet. Also, could the premise be weakened?

Comment: Would you mind including a formulation of the statement from the other question here?

Comment: No, give me a moment :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it works. The "proof" hinges on the premise that $\bigcup(F\cap G)$ is non-empty.

Your added condition implies that $\bigcup(F\cap G)\neq\varnothing$, so the proof works out.